# Why can't I access other page than default page on Magento?

Tags: php, nginx, magento-1.9

Hi every one I am new to magento. I've been trying to install magento 1.9.0.0 on with nginx server on Ubuntu 14.04LTS but I can't get started. I can see default page see below

[magento default page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hVQn.png)

but whenever I try to log in it, server fails with UNABLE TO CONNECT error.

here is my virtual host

```
server {
    listen   80;
    listen   [::]:80;
    server_name www.mymagento.com;
    root /var/www/magento;
    index index.php;
    #need it to execute php
    location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi_params;
    include fastcgi.conf;
    }
```

}

I already tried other solution like updating core_config_data web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url they contain my base url.
I tried reloading cache. there is nothing in nginx log neiher.

Thank you for helping me :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have nothing to redirect URIs to the Magento common front handler. As a minimum you should add:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

But I suggest that you check [this site](https://wiki.magento.com/display/m1wiki/Configuring+nginx+for+Magento+1.x) for more.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I was not aware that I have to redirect to common front handler. I added your lines but unfortunately, it still does not work. How can I redirect each URIs to front handler ? I am new to nginx also

Answer (score 0):

Hi as Richard SMITH said, my virtual host was missing some lines to somehow redirect to front handler. As I have just begin to use Nginx, I won't be able to explain each lines but after strugling with Nginx this config works for me (I also needed to add self signed certificate to config to make it work).

```
server {
    listen   80;
    listen   [::]:80;
    listen 443 default ssl;
    server_name www.mymagento.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;
    root /var/www/magento;
    index index.php;


    location / {
            index index.html index.php;
            autoindex on;
            #If missing pass the URI to Magento's front handler
            try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
            expires max; 
 }

    #need it to execute php
    location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi_params;
    include fastcgi.conf;
    }

    ## Magento uses a common front handler
    location @handler {
    rewrite / /index.php;
    }


}
```